# jar file is not including in build.xml

Tags: jar

What could be the reasons for a jar file not to include in build, even everything was given correctly. I tried the same syntax with other jar files which worked. But when i am using it for protocol buffers jar file, it is not being included.

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you need to include a build.xml in the final jar? How are you packaging your jar?

Comment: I am trying to use ant for building my project, for which i need to write a build.xml. I need to include protocol buffer jar file in the project. So i kept it in build.xml which is not working